# How to install Dell EMC System Update (DSU)?

Tags: server, dell

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell server. Console access only, no GUI.

Ubuntu is listed as a supported platform for DSU, for example:

- https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000130590/dell-emc-system-update-dsu
- https://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/DSU_19.05.00/

However, I've not found any instruction on where to get it or how to install it. Only details for RPM packages are given.

Perhaps there is no package and you have to install the binary directly? I found this, but it lists Windows and RedHat only: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=8CTK7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea if this is what Dell intended, but I managed to get something working:

1. Download latest DSU linux installer: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=8ctk7
2. Run it or extract the .deb from it and install separately
3. Delete `/usr/lib/dsulib/libcurl.so.4`
4. Install missing dependencies: `libcurl4` and `libgpgme11`

It then appears to be possible to e.g. `dsu --apply-upgrades` and it installs new drivers.

I have complained to the listed package maintainer. I'm not holding my breath that they will fix anything.

---

For the latest version (1.9.3.0), `dsulib` should contain the following:

```
libcmtredfish.so.7.4.0
libdrone.so
libdsmbase.so
libdsmcabinet.so
libdsmsignverifier.so
libdsmxml.so
libduecC.so.2.0.0.1
```

And the package control should have:

```
Depends: libcurl4, libcurl3-gnutls, libgpgme11, libicu66, libminizip1, libstdc++6, libuuid1, libxerces-c3.2, libxml2
```

You also need the separate .asc keys from inside the installer moved into the package at `/usr/libexec/dell_dup`.

---

For 2.0.2.0 the `dsulib` contents should be the same, with a slight change to dependencies:

```
Depends: libcurl4, libcurl3-gnutls, libgpgme11, libicu70, libminizip1, libstdc++6, libuuid1, libxerces-c3.2, libxml2
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested DSU 1.7 (uses Dell EMC Linux Repository v19.5) on 20.04LTS and, although it installs, it doesn't work.

DSU for 18.04 https://dl.dell.com/FOLDER05327755M/1/Systems-Management_Application_FT56W_LN64_1.6.0_A00.BIN

Unfortunately, it requires a number of library dependencies that don't exist in 20.04, at least under the same name.

The dsu command is nice enough to tell you what libraries are missing :-)

You might be able to get it working with enough searching through 20.04 repos.

Comment: So much for "officially supported".

Comment: There's also this from (https://linux.dell.com/repo/hardware/dsu/ ), which seems to indicate they aren't supporting Ubuntu in 14G and later.
 
> Note: DSU Ubuntu enablement is only available for 12G and 13G systems